# <!DOCTYPE html> creating problems for my footer

Tags: html, footer, doctype

I noticed that whenever I put `<!DOCTYPE html>` on my html document, the footer disappears. And I need to get no errors whenever I validate, so how do I fix this? thank you

The footer is show below.

```css
#footer {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 20;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="footer">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Privacy/Disclaimer Statement</button>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        alert("David's Pet Store will never share any of your private information outside of its committee. The website builder is also protected from any incorrect information posted by a pet owner.");
      }
    </script>
    <br>David's Pet Store - 2016
    <br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome 48 on OS X http://output.jsbin.com/felawo/ In which browsers are you seeing this issue?

Comment: chrome, edge, and explorer!

Comment: Tested on Firefox 30,Chrome 48 and IE 10, works fine.Although the alert doesn't trigger in IE.

Comment: Mad it into a runable snippet

Comment: What you have shown seems to work OK.  I think the problem must be elsewhere in code you did not share.  Could there maybe be another element with an id of footer?  An unclosed tag? etc...

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need ? your code is 100% correct but u may forgot `px` so that problems appear try my code for 0px at buttom or 20px as you need ^_^

```css
#footer {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="footer">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Privacy/Disclaimer Statement</button>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        alert("David's Pet Store will never share any of your private information outside of its committee. The website builder is also protected from any incorrect information posted by a pet owner.");
      }
    </script>
    <br>David's Pet Store - 2016
    <br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

or u can see [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6mL42zr/) for 20**px** at buttom

Comment: Are you going to explain what you changed and why, or do visitors have to figure this by themselves somehow?

Comment: he forgot the `px` word

Comment: *"I have moved the footer to the very down that's all "* I noticed (after a while) that you changed `bottom: 20` to `bottom: 0`. You should call that out explicitly and explain why you changed it. E.g. explain what's wrong with `bottom: 20`. Just reposting the whole code with one line change without explaining it is not helpful.